# Changing orientation of DatePicker in Android

Tags: android, datepicker

I'm trying to make a date picker and a time picker. It appears that the orientation of the the picker itself is based on the orientation of the screen, not sure about that though, but my screen is horizontal.

As you can see in the picture, the green bar is on the left and the calendar view is on the right, I want the bar to be on top and calendar on bottom, usually this is how date picker look in a DatePckerDialog (I'm not using dialog).

I can't seem to find a way to flip this.

[image]